# How to Replace text characters only in a column with date values but of VARCHAR data type in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, regex, date

I have a table with a column of dates which has had various values that have been cleansed from Excel dates etc to mysql dates and the last step that I want to run is to remove any non-date values in the column before I run an alter command to change the data type to DATE but unfortunately the query that I have written is giving me a few issues. The following is a sample of my dates:

```
CREATE TABLE `date_checks` 
        (  
        `Start_Date` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
        );
```

My Insert Statements:

```
INSERT INTO `date_checks` (`Start_Date`) VALUES
('04/04/2018'),
('01/05/2018'),
('3 years'),
('28/05/2018');
```

My Output

```
Start_Date
    04/04/2018
    01/05/2018
    3 years
    28/05/2018
```

The query that I am running is the following:

```
UPDATE 'date_checks' SET Start_Date = '' WHERE Start_Date NOT REGEXP '^[0-9]';
```

Now I am guessing because I have the value 3 at the start of my 3rd row, this won't get deleted, so I just wanted to get some help to make sure I do this the right way as all I would like in this column is date values. The REGEXP I have written is looking for everything that does not begin with a number but I am guessing I need to expand this to the way the dates are in the column for it to be more specific and accurate.

If the above code runs OK, then I will run the following to change the data type:

```
ALTER TABLE date_checks MODIFY Start_Date DATE;
```

Would appreciate it, if somebody could advise that I am going about this the right way.

Comment: So what are you going to do with `3 years` that wont become a MySQL DATE datatype or andthing in this format `28/05/2018`

Comment: How did you load the excel data in the first place. Is this a One Off process or a regular one

Comment: The 3 years value has to become an empty value so a NULL as this value is not acceptable in this column. The total data in my full database is 1.5 million rows, the examples I have given is the random ones I have come across that are causing the issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL doesn't understand dates in DD/MM/YYYY format. If you do the ALTER TABLE statement you show, it will fail to convert those dates into their DATE type value.

You need to convert the strings to YYYY-MM-DD format.

I'd suggest starting with a new column:

```
ALTER TABLE date_checks ADD COLUMN Start_Date2 DATE;
```

Then copy the values to the new column.

```
UPDATE date_checks SET Start_Date2 = STR_TO_DATE(Start_Date, '%d/%m/%Y');
```

If a string like '3 years' isn't in a format that matches the format string in that function, then STR_TO_DATE() returns NULL.

So after this UPDATE you will have most of your dates copied into the proper format, but those that couldn't be parsed will be NULL.

Then you can check for oddball cases that failed to be parsed. These might be few enough that you want to update them in the new column manually.

```
SELECT Start_Date FROM date_checks WHERE Start_Date2 IS NULL;
```

After you've manually assigned any you want to keep, the remaining Start_Date strings are not worth keeping. Then you can feel free to drop the old column, and rename the new column.

```
ALTER TABLE date_checks DROP COLUMN Start_Date, 
    CHANGE COLUMN Start_Date2 Start_Date DATE;
```

---

Re your comment:

> How would I change the Update Code to accept both?

I don't know that it's necessary to do this in one pass. You could do it in several passes:

```
UPDATE date_checks SET Start_Date2 = STR_TO_DATE(Start_Date, '%d/%m/%Y');
UPDATE date_checks SET Start_Date2 = STR_TO_DATE(Start_Date, '%d-%m-%Y') WHERE Start_Date2 IS NULL;
UPDATE date_checks SET Start_Date2 = STR_TO_DATE(Start_Date, '%d.%m.%Y') WHERE Start_Date2 IS NULL;
...other formats...
```

So after each pass, fewer rows would still have NULL for the Start_Date2. You keep trying other formats as needed, until either there aren't any more NULLs, or you want to give up because the last few stragglers aren't parseable.

Like what do you do if there's one left, but the string in `Start_Date` reads, "as old as my tongue and a little bit older than my teeth"?

If you really need it to be done in one pass, you can use COALESCE() with several tries:

```
UPDATE date_checks SET Start_Date2 = COALESCE(
  STR_TO_DATE(Start_Date, '%d/%m/%Y'),
  STR_TO_DATE(Start_Date, '%d-%m-%Y'),
  STR_TO_DATE(Start_Date, '%d.%m.%Y')
  ...other formats...
);
```

COALESCE() returns its first non-NULL argument. So it will try each of these STR_TO_DATE() calls in order, left-to-right, and the result will be first one that succeeds. Or else NULL if none succeed.

Comment: Thank you Bill, I will go through your suggestions and let you know how i get on.

Comment: Hi Bill, I have just ran through the process you mentioned on my main table and just come across some dates that have the divider value as '-' instead of '/'. How would I change the Update Code to accept both?

Comment: I mean the delimiter between the date parts.

Comment: Thank you so much Bill, for the detailed explanation, this helped me alot and I have managed to fix my date issues,